# Regex to match phone numbers, but in text paragraph

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I would like to highlight phone numbers in a text with the PHP function preg_replace().

This works pretty well:

```
(?=(?:\D*\d\D*){8,14}$)[- \d()+]*
```

It almost matches those different formats:

```
01 02 03 04 05
0102030405
+33102030405 01-02-03-04-05
01.02.03.04.05
+33 1 02 03 04 053
(33)102030405
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/LHgmxn/2)

But now I would like to make it running with this test text:

> blabla 01 02 03 04 05 blabla 0102030405 blabla +33102030405 blabla
> 01-02-03-04-05 blabla 01.02.03.04.05 blabla +33 1 02 03 04 05 blabla
> (33)102030405

I do not speak fluently regex, I've tried many things but failed.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/MSTgXI/1)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try `[+(]?\d(?:[-()+\s]*\d){8,14}(?![-()+\s]*\d)`

Comment: Thnks Wictor, but 01.02.03.04.05 does not match anymore

Comment: got them with [+(]?\d(?:[-()+\s\.]*\d){8,14}(?![ -()+\s]*\d) Thanks a lot Wiktor !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
[+(]?\d(?:[-()+\s.]*\d){8,14}(?![-()+\s.]*\d)
```

*Details*:

- `[+(]?` - an optional `+` or `(`
- `\d` - a  digit
- `(?:[-()+\s.]*\d){8,14}` - eight to 14 occurrences of a `-`, `(`, `)`, `+`, whitespace or `.` char and then a digit
- `(?![-()+\s.]*\d)` - not immediately followed with a `-`, `(`, `)`, `+`, whitespace or `.` char and then a digit.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/giSA9Y/1).